# When installing an enterprise .ipa getting "Unable to Download App"

Tags: ios, xcode, ipa

System Info:

- Mac mini - MacOS 10.12.6
- iPhone 6 - iOS 11.0.2 - Not connected to wifi, using only cellular data, no VPN
- XCode Beta 9.1 (9B46)
- We have an active enterprise membership

After creating the .ipa file I am hosting the manifest.plist and .ipa file on a file server. When I click the link to the manifest.plist file I get the prompt to install the application. I click Install but then a few seconds later I get the message 'Unable to Download App: "TrueID IDMi" could not be downloaded at this time'.

I am creating the .ipa file using these instructions:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps.html

I tested to see if I could download the .ipa from iOS Safari to see if it was a firewall issue but I am able to download the .ipa and save it to iCloud. So I think that elinimates that possibility.

I opened the iPhone console in the Console.app program and did a grep during the installation for our apps bundle ID "TrueIDIDMi". I get the below output. Line 20 makes me wonder if there is there is a problem with my bundle ID. We have used com.lexisnexis.risk.TrueIDIDMi in the past for internal releases and com.lexisnexis.risk.TrueIDIDM for App Store releases so I would be surprised if that is the issue.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
default 10:40:46.329318 -0500 SpringBoard Received request to activate alertItem: <SBUserNotificationAlert: 0x10ae78a50; title: dl.dropboxusercontent.com would like to install “TrueID IDMi”; source: itunesstored; pid: 111>
default 10:40:46.330460 -0500 SpringBoard Activation - Presenting <SBUserNotificationAlert: 0x10ae78a50; title: dl.dropboxusercontent.com would like to install “TrueID IDMi”; source: itunesstored; pid: 111> with presenter: <SBUnlockedAlertItemPresenter: 0x1c401f450>
default 10:40:47.699748 -0500 SpringBoard Deactivated alertItem: <SBUserNotificationAlert: 0x10ae78a50; title: dl.dropboxusercontent.com would like to install “TrueID IDMi”; source: itunesstored; pid: 111>
default 10:40:47.700230 -0500 SpringBoard Deactivated alertItem: <SBUserNotificationAlert: 0x10ae78a50; title: dl.dropboxusercontent.com would like to install “TrueID IDMi”; source: itunesstored; pid: 111>
default 10:40:47.720788 -0500 appstored [JobTransaction]: Imported download: 3119198823505452030 for bundle: com.lexisnexis.risk.TrueIDIDMi evid: (null)
default 10:40:47.721363 -0500 appstored [InstallManifestRequestOperation]: Added job: 3119198823505452030 / com.lexisnexis.risk.TrueIDIDMi
default 10:40:47.725323 -0500 appstored com.lexisnexis.risk.TrueIDIDMi:3:1:1:1:Creating an install coordinator
default 10:40:47.768134 -0500 appstored com.lexisnexis.risk.TrueIDIDMi:3:1:2:1:Coordination creation suceeded
default 10:40:47.961576 -0500 appstored [PlaceholderUtility]: Successfully set placeholder for bundleID: com.lexisnexis.risk.TrueIDIDMi
default 10:40:47.994242 -0500 installcoordinationd com.lexisnexis.risk.TrueIDIDMi:5:11:1:1:Updating PlaceholderMetadata for com.lexisnexis.risk.TrueIDIDMi with LSInstallType 1
default 10:40:48.004294 -0500 installd 0x16ed57000 -[MIClientConnection updatePlaceholderMetadataForApp:installType:failureReason:underlyingError:failureSource:completion:]: Update placeholder metadata requested by client installcoordinationd (pid 104) for app com.lexisnexis.risk.TrueIDIDMi installType = 1 failureReason = 0 underlyingError = (null) failureSource = 0
default 10:40:48.040381 -0500 SpringBoard -[FBApplicationLibrary applicationInstallsDidStart:] com.lexisnexis.risk.TrueIDIDMi
default 10:40:48.065251 -0500 installcoordinationd com.lexisnexis.risk.TrueIDIDMi:5:11:2:1:Updated PlaceholderMetadata for app with error (null)
default 10:40:48.070958 -0500 lsd com.lexisnexis.risk.TrueIDIDMi:5:11:1:1:Updating bundle record for app (placeholderMetadata)
default 10:40:48.073728 -0500 SpringBoard com.lexisnexis.risk.TrueIDIDMi:10:2:3:1:Reloading icon image.
default 10:40:48.089749 -0500 lsd com.lexisnexis.risk.TrueIDIDMi:5:11:2:1:Updated bundle record
error 10:40:48.091840 -0500 CommCenter LaunchServices reports com.lexisnexis.risk.TrueIDIDMi is not installed
default 10:40:48.345707 -0500 appstored [PlaceholderUtility]: Loading artwork for placeholder for: com.lexisnexis.risk.TrueIDIDMi
default 10:40:48.346101 -0500 appstored [PlaceholderUtility]: Adding thumbnail promise for bundleID: com.lexisnexis.risk.TrueIDIDMi
error 10:40:48.378693 -0500 appstored [InstallManifestRequestOperation]: Failed to create placeholder for bundleID: com.lexisnexis.risk.TrueIDIDMi error: (null)
default 10:40:48.418539 -0500 appstored [JobScheduler]: Found startable job 3119198823505452030 / com.lexisnexis.risk.TrueIDIDMi for bucket: User Initiated
default 10:40:48.419172 -0500 appstored [JobScheduler]: Starting job: 3119198823505452030 / com.lexisnexis.risk.TrueIDIDMi | ORDER: 1152921504606846984
default 10:40:48.464796 -0500 appstored [JobPreflightChecksOperation]: Running preflight checks for job 3119198823505452030 / com.lexisnexis.risk.TrueIDIDMi
default 10:40:48.465890 -0500 appstored com.lexisnexis.risk.TrueIDIDMi:3:1:1:1:Creating an install coordinator
default 10:40:48.467372 -0500 appstored !B30:com.lexisnexis.risk.TrueIDIDMi,J:3119198823505452030#[<private>]: Passing empty array for initial ODR promises since this app does not require any
default 10:40:48.467895 -0500 appstored com.lexisnexis.risk.TrueIDIDMi:3:1:2:1:Coordination creation suceeded
default 10:40:48.497118 -0500 appstored !B30:com.lexisnexis.risk.TrueIDIDMi,J:3119198823505452030#[<private>]: Software download failed, handling failure
default 10:40:48.544379 -0500 installd 0x16eccb000 -[MIClientConnection updatePlaceholderMetadataForApp:installType:failureReason:underlyingError:failureSource:completion:]: Update placeholder metadata requested by client installcoordinationd (pid 104) for app com.lexisnexis.risk.TrueIDIDMi installType = 1 failureReason = 1 underlyingError = Error Domain=SSErrorDomain Code=100 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot connect to iTunes Store} failureSource = 1
default 10:40:48.550383 -0500 installcoordinationd com.lexisnexis.risk.TrueIDIDMi:5:11:1:1:Updating PlaceholderMetadata for com.lexisnexis.risk.TrueIDIDMi with failure 1 <LSInstallType 1, underlyingError (Error Domain=SSErrorDomain Code=100 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot connect to iTunes Store}), source 1>
default 10:40:48.582961 -0500 lsd com.lexisnexis.risk.TrueIDIDMi:5:11:1:1:Updating bundle record for app (placeholderMetadata)
default 10:40:48.583515 -0500 lsd com.lexisnexis.risk.TrueIDIDMi:5:11:2:1:Updated bundle record
default 10:40:48.584853 -0500 installcoordinationd com.lexisnexis.risk.TrueIDIDMi:5:11:2:1:Updated PlaceholderMetadata for app with error (null)
error 10:40:48.628449 -0500 symptomsd LaunchServices reports com.lexisnexis.risk.TrueIDIDMi is not installed
default 10:40:51.048290 -0500 SpringBoard Received request to activate alertItem: <SBUserNotificationAlert: 0x10bd2f580; title: dl.dropboxusercontent.com would like to install “TrueID IDMi”; source: itunesstored; pid: 111>
default 10:40:51.048819 -0500 SpringBoard Activation - Presenting <SBUserNotificationAlert: 0x10bd2f580; title: dl.dropboxusercontent.com would like to install “TrueID IDMi”; source: itunesstored; pid: 111> with presenter: <SBUnlockedAlertItemPresenter: 0x1c401f450>
default 10:40:57.884123 -0500 SpringBoard Deactivated alertItem: <SBUserNotificationAlert: 0x10bd2f580; title: dl.dropboxusercontent.com would like to install “TrueID IDMi”; source: itunesstored; pid: 111>
default 10:40:57.887612 -0500 SpringBoard Deactivated alertItem: <SBUserNotificationAlert: 0x10bd2f580; title: dl.dropboxusercontent.com would like to install “TrueID IDMi”; source: itunesstored; pid: 111>
default 10:40:57.893484 -0500 appstored [JobTransaction]: Imported download: 7947567809452592207 for bundle: com.lexisnexis.risk.TrueIDIDMi evid: (null)
default 10:40:57.901221 -0500 appstored [InstallManifestRequestOperation]: Added job: 7947567809452592207 / com.lexisnexis.risk.TrueIDIDMi
default 10:40:57.901968 -0500 appstored com.lexisnexis.risk.TrueIDIDMi:3:1:1:1:Creating an install coordinator
default 10:40:57.916260 -0500 appstored com.lexisnexis.risk.TrueIDIDMi:3:1:2:1:Coordination creation suceeded
default 10:40:57.952386 -0500 appstored [PlaceholderUtility]: Successfully set placeholder for bundleID: com.lexisnexis.risk.TrueIDIDMi
default 10:40:58.110021 -0500 installcoordinationd com.lexisnexis.risk.TrueIDIDMi:5:11:1:1:Updating PlaceholderMetadata for com.lexisnexis.risk.TrueIDIDMi with LSInstallType 1
default 10:40:58.113943 -0500 installd 0x16ed57000 -[MIClientConnection updatePlaceholderMetadataForApp:installType:failureReason:underlyingError:failureSource:completion:]: Update placeholder metadata requested by client installcoordinationd (pid 104) for app com.lexisnexis.risk.TrueIDIDMi installType = 1 failureReason = 0 underlyingError = (null) failureSource = 0
default 10:40:58.116719 -0500 lsd com.lexisnexis.risk.TrueIDIDMi:5:11:1:1:Updating bundle record for app (placeholderMetadata)
default 10:40:58.117080 -0500 lsd com.lexisnexis.risk.TrueIDIDMi:5:11:2:1:Updated bundle record
default 10:40:58.119041 -0500 SpringBoard -[FBApplicationLibrary applicationInstallsDidStart:] com.lexisnexis.risk.TrueIDIDMi
default 10:40:58.123829 -0500 installcoordinationd com.lexisnexis.risk.TrueIDIDMi:5:11:2:1:Updated PlaceholderMetadata for app with error (null)
default 10:40:58.126090 -0500 SpringBoard com.lexisnexis.risk.TrueIDIDMi:10:2:3:1:Reloading icon image.
error 10:40:58.137780 -0500 CommCenter LaunchServices reports com.lexisnexis.risk.TrueIDIDMi is not installed
default 10:40:58.771963 -0500 appstored [PlaceholderUtility]: Loading artwork for placeholder for: com.lexisnexis.risk.TrueIDIDMi
default 10:40:58.772125 -0500 appstored [PlaceholderUtility]: Adding thumbnail promise for bundleID: com.lexisnexis.risk.TrueIDIDMi
error 10:40:58.821204 -0500 appstored [InstallManifestRequestOperation]: Failed to create placeholder for bundleID: com.lexisnexis.risk.TrueIDIDMi error: (null)
default 10:40:58.825348 -0500 appstored [JobScheduler]: Found startable job 7947567809452592207 / com.lexisnexis.risk.TrueIDIDMi for bucket: User Initiated
default 10:40:58.826468 -0500 appstored [JobScheduler]: Starting job: 7947567809452592207 / com.lexisnexis.risk.TrueIDIDMi | ORDER: 1152921504606846985
default 10:40:58.835155 -0500 appstored [JobPreflightChecksOperation]: Running preflight checks for job 7947567809452592207 / com.lexisnexis.risk.TrueIDIDMi
default 10:40:58.835643 -0500 appstored com.lexisnexis.risk.TrueIDIDMi:3:1:1:1:Creating an install coordinator
default 10:40:58.843401 -0500 appstored !B30:com.lexisnexis.risk.TrueIDIDMi,J:7947567809452592207#[<private>]: Passing empty array for initial ODR promises since this app does not require any
default 10:40:58.850952 -0500 appstored com.lexisnexis.risk.TrueIDIDMi:3:1:2:1:Coordination creation suceeded
default 10:40:58.869597 -0500 appstored !B30:com.lexisnexis.risk.TrueIDIDMi,J:7947567809452592207#[<private>]: Software download failed, handling failure
default 10:40:58.910630 -0500 installcoordinationd com.lexisnexis.risk.TrueIDIDMi:5:11:1:1:Updating PlaceholderMetadata for com.lexisnexis.risk.TrueIDIDMi with failure 1 <LSInstallType 1, underlyingError (Error Domain=SSErrorDomain Code=100 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot connect to iTunes Store}), source 1>
default 10:40:58.913810 -0500 installd 0x16ed57000 -[MIClientConnection updatePlaceholderMetadataForApp:installType:failureReason:underlyingError:failureSource:completion:]: Update placeholder metadata requested by client installcoordinationd (pid 104) for app com.lexisnexis.risk.TrueIDIDMi installType = 1 failureReason = 1 underlyingError = Error Domain=SSErrorDomain Code=100 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot connect to iTunes Store} failureSource = 1
default 10:40:58.954626 -0500 lsd com.lexisnexis.risk.TrueIDIDMi:5:11:1:1:Updating bundle record for app (placeholderMetadata)
default 10:40:58.955142 -0500 lsd com.lexisnexis.risk.TrueIDIDMi:5:11:2:1:Updated bundle record
default 10:40:58.956451 -0500 installcoordinationd com.lexisnexis.risk.TrueIDIDMi:5:11:2:1:Updated PlaceholderMetadata for app with error (null)
error 10:40:59.391319 -0500 symptomsd LaunchServices reports com.lexisnexis.risk.TrueIDIDMi is not installed
```

Comment: Not sure if this will work, but try with (create a build) stable version of Xcode

Comment: Here are few suggestions: https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX139444

Comment: I am going to try to go back to Xcode 8

Comment: I saw that article previously and I have checked each possible issue they have suggested. If I am not mistaken I do not need to worry about the provisioning profile or device UUID because I am trying to export the app for enterprise.

Comment: Try using Xcode 9.1 stable version, you have mentioned you are using Xcode 9.1 beta. I'm working with Xcode 9.1 stable version on enterprise app and just 2 days ago I released my recent build.

Answer (score 1):

Bundle Identifier in the application Info.plist and the Bundle Identifier in the installation plist must be identical.

Moreover, it seems that if there is a mismatch, the iPad will "remember" the old plist over any newer version you may upload. Fixing that particular issue by rebooting the iPad usually works.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue, but then we realized that we we're signing the application with the Developper certificate instead of the Production one.